# Dynamically add new elements and add new sub-element on the selected element in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and I'm wondering on how to achieve this below sample.

Section 1
-- Sub Section 1
-- Sub Section 2
-- Sub Section 3

Section 2
-- Sub Section 1
-- Sub Section 2

Where user can add more Sections dynamically and from that section he/she can add more sub sections dynamically. Also, how can i get the index of specific element. Hope I explained it properly. Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many ways to do this, one of them could be to initialize an array for Parent Sections and other for child sections. The child would keep knowledge about who its parent is.

See the working plunker here: [Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/rSr9QSBmh1B8Xuce9xrK?p=preview)

Two arrays:

```
$scope.section = [{id: 1}, {id:2}];

$scope.subSection = [{id:1, parentId: 1}, {id:2, parentId: 1},{id:3, parentId: 2}];
```

View:

```
<div ng-repeat="parent in section">
   <span>Section {{parent.id}}</span>
     <pre>
     <div ng-repeat="child in subSection" ng-if="child.parentId == parent.id">
        <span>SubSection {{child.id}}</span>
     </div>
      <button ng-click="addSubSection($index + 1)">Add SubSection</button>
     </pre>
</div>
<button ng-click="addSection()">Add Section</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Dev-One . I really appreciate it. This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="section in sections">
  {{ section.name }}
  <div ng-repeat="subsection in section.subsections">
     {{ subsection.name }}
  </div>
  <button ng-click="addSubsectionTo(section)">Add subsection</button>
</div>
<button ng-click="addSection()">Add section</button>
```